# xamarin forms webview.eval return type is voide . How to retrieve user input data?

Tags: xamarin, webview, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xlabs

I am working on xamarin.forms. I have a content page which contains one webview which load 3rd party url(www.xyz.com) site and one button in shell.

On button click event I am trying to get user input data using

```
webview.eval(javascript: var data = document.getElementById('first-name').value;alert(data)).
```

It works fine but due to void return type I could not store data in local variable and I have a `customrender(webviewrender)` but don't know on shell button click event how can I get userinput data from webview

Please suggest me how do I achieve this functionality.I do not want XLab-Hybridwebview.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to have the JavaScript code call out to the external code when the result is available. You could then wrap that whole process in a TaskCompletionSource to make everything nice and easy to use.

Comment: If you do not mind can you please give me a complete simple example so that I can start with my code .  ---Thanks in advance

Comment: @ShubhrajitBiswas Were you able to implement joe solution ?